# Check if a Vector contains a string always fails

Tags: java, xpages

in this code snippet:

```
s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
Vector<String> groups = s.getUserGroupNameList();
if (debug) System.out.println("User groups are " + groups);
Boolean n = groups.contains("Notes_Admin");
if (debug) System.out.println("n = " + n);
if ( n ){
    if (debug) System.out.println("Groups Contains Notes_Admin");
}else{
    if (debug) System.out.println("Groups does not contain Notes_Admin");
}
```

the value for n always returns false even though I know that the Vector groups does in fact contain the value "Notes_Admin". I also tried groups.indexOF("Notes_Admin") with it always returning -1. I'm guessing that I have misdefined type somewhere in there but I've tried all the combinations that I can think of. The getUserGroupsNameList says that it returns a Vector.

Comment: _does in fact contain_ Prove it.

Comment: How do you know that for a fact?  Why not print out the contents before the `if (n)`?

Comment: because this line appears in the console log 
if (debug) System.out.println("User groups are " + groups);
and the log says:
02/02/2015 05:23:03 PM  HTTP JVM: User groups are [*/O=Workflo Systems, Replicators, Notes_Admin, NewNormal, HF-Users, NH-Managers, MCS, paypal, Accounting, Credit, Marketing, spamJam Administrators, Administrators, LocalDomainAdmins, Workflo Systems, Webmasters, Notes Administrators, Eve

The third item in groups is Notes_Admin

Comment: Are you sure those are all entries? Log the size of `groups`.

Comment: What does `groups.get(2).equals("Notes_Admin")` produce? Are you sure that there are no spaces? I cannot see that from you output.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss: you are 100% correct there is a leading space infron of each of the string values. Now why s.getUserGroupNameList(); would do that is another issue. So I will need to replace the leading spaces and it should work. Thanks.

Comment: You should also be using `ArrayList` unless you need your collection to be thread-safe, but that is only for performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that Session's `getUserGroupNameList()` doesn't return a list of Strings but a list of `lotus.domino.local.Name`.

Change your code to

```
import lotus.domino.local.Name;
...
      Vector<Name> groups = s.getUserGroupNameList();
      System.out.println("User groups are " + groups);
      Boolean n = false;
      for (Name group : groups) {
          if (group.getCommon().equals("Notes_Admin")) {
              n = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      System.out.println("n = " + n);
```

Comment: Just a note: Name is one of the most toxic Domino objects (comes from session) an needs to be recycled in loop :-) With average ~50 groups a user and ~200 concurrent HTTP users/threads this code will crash the server.

Comment: @Frantisek: good point, so, no `break` and a `group.recycle()` at the end of every loop OR an own for-each-recycle-loop at the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Especially the  recycle bit. Here is my final code:
Vector<Name> groups = s.getUserGroupNameList();
for (Name group : groups) {
    if (group.getAbbreviated().equals(thisValue)) {
 internalMap.add(thisMenu);
 group.recycle();
 break;
    }else{//is group =
 group.recycle();
    }
}//End for Name group : groups